# Register map implementation in VHDL

Tags: arrays, vhdl

In my design I am trying to create a register map, which can be used by separate components in a flexible way. For example, let's say I create a following register map type:

```
package regmap_package is

    type regmap_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

end package regmap_package;
```

So this would be my register map with x amount of 8 bit registers. In my top entity I then declare the total size of the register map:

```
signal regs : regmap_t(0 to 15);
```

So in this example I would have 16 x 8 bit register map. Here comes my problem: Lets say I want to create some sub-components. Each of that component, would only need some portion of these register to operate with.

For example component1 would need the register from address 0 to address 7, and components 2 registers from address 8 to address 15. How would the entity declaration for such component look like and how to pass the portion of the whole register array to it? Will the components operate on its own, local addressing schemes (from 0 to 7 each)?

Comment: It all depends on scale. 16x8 is pretty small, so you can probably just have a single decode and pipe the registers to the blocks. When you get larger (like 64k per module, with many modules) you'll probably want a crossbar to separate each component access, then you might want sub-crossbars to break it up again. It all depends on your design. Monolithic register decodes just become unmanageable. At the end though, its usually easiest to have a record type for each module containing relavent registers, and decoding them elsewhere.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for answer. There will not be more than 16x8 and surely not as much as 64k. The issue is only that I need a single register map and each components should only use parts of the registers and doesnt need to know about the whole implementation. For example, if I have 16x8 bit map, there could be a components that needs to see the whole map, to show the registers content on a led display but on the other hand, there could be a components that only needs registers from 5 to 7 and for him, those are addresses from 0 to 2.

Comment: Then its usually just easiest to send the bits that are needed. Ideally with meaningful names: block_en <= ctrl_reg(4)(7);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an enumeration to declare register names:

```
type RegisterNames is (Command, Status, VendorID, DeviceID, Error);
```

Now you can create your register map:

```
type RegisterType is array(RegisterNames range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

By using `range <>`, you can create any range of that type.

From here you can generate your register map:

```
signal RegisterMap : RegisterType(RegisterNames);
```

You can slice this register map as follows:

```
signal SubRegisters : RegisterType(VendorID to DeviceID);
SubRegister <= RegisterMap(SubRegister'range);
```

## Answers to comments

> Can a package be created with the global labels available to be used as indexes?

Yes, you can define the described enumeration type in a package. Thus, the register names and the register type itself is available to be used as ports and in higher level entities.

Unfortunately, VHDL-2008 has a broken support for incomplete generic types. You could pass an enumeration type into a package and then pass that instantiated package into an entity implementing a generic register interface e.g. for AXI4 Lite, but that generic type comes with no operations. Thus, you have no operators and no attributes of a generic type available.

How would it look like?

```
package GenericRegisterPackage is
  generic (
    constant ShortName        : string;   -- e.g. PWM
    type     RegisterNames;
    constant AXI4_AddressBits : positive;
    constant AXI4_DataBits    : positive
  );

  subtype RegisterType is std_logic_vector(AXI4_DataBits - 1 downto 0);

  -- THE FOLLOWING LINE IS NOT SUPPORTED in VHDL-2008
  type    RegisterFile is array(RegisterNames range <>) of RegisterType;

end package;

entity GenericAXI4LiteRegister is
  generic (
    package GenericRegisterPackage
  );
  port (
    Clock : in std_logic;
    -- ...
  );
end entity;
```

**Usage:**

```
architecture rtl of Controller is
  type RegisterNames is (Command, Status, Error, Frequency);

  package RegisterPackage is new work.GenericAXI4LiteRegister
    generic map (
      ShortName        => "PWM Controller",
      RegisterNames    => RegisterNames,
      AXI4_AddressBits => 8,
      AXI4_DataBits    => 32
    );
begin
  reg: entity work.GenericAXI4LiteRegister
    generic map (
      GenericRegisterPackage => RegisterPackage
    )
    port map (
      Clock => Clock,
      -- ...
    );
end architecture;
```

This misconception of VHDL-2008 will be fixed in VHDL-2018. The following line from the package's incomplete generic type:

```
type RegisterNames;
```

will become this:

```
type RegisterNames is ();
```

...denoting, it is an enumeration type. Thus, it's a discrete type and can be used as an index in arrays.

> Also, is specific index setting (natural number) possible here?

Yes, you can convert enumeration literals to indices. Every discrete type (including enumerations) has position numbers for all its values.

```
constant position : natural := RegisterNames'pos(VendorID);
```

will return `2`. The positions starts at 0 for the left-most enumeration literal in the declaration. Every following literal to the right gets a positions incremented by 1.

The reverse operation from position number (natural) to an enumeration literal it  the attribute `'val(5)`, which returns `Error`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can a package be created with the global labels available to be used as indexes? Also, is specific index setting (natural number) possible here?

Comment: Thank you for this. It is a bit to grasp, I will try implementing it tommorow and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I am marking your answer as best, but I will not implement this into the code. Its a bit too complicated for me and it feels like the ideology of a proper register map initialization becomes more important than easy of use. I am still not certain how to implement th my working code. The best solution which I came up with is a package with natural constants that indicate the register numbers and register bits. I dont like this solution but its easy to understand for the user of the code (and easy to use). Thanks again for your time.